# Docker container is not restarted with --restart=always

Tags: docker

I have a service that is run in docker container. I start it as following:

```
docker run --gpus device=$gpu -it --restart=always --ulimit core=-1 --network host $addon_arg $cert_arg \
        --entrypoint "my_server" my_server_debug:latest --port 444 --ip 0.0.0.0 \
        --threads 64 --batch_size 64 --addon /opt/model.addon \
        --cert /opt/cert.pem --key /opt/key.pem $auth_arg 2>&1 | tee $(date +"%Y%m%d-%H").log
```

At times, `my_server` fails with segfault. I am still debugging why, but in the meantime, I want the container to automatically restart so the service stays available as much as possible. For some reason container does not get restarted. In status I see smth like: `Exited (137) 37 minutes ago` and thats it. How do I properly use restart functionality? How can I debug why it does'nt restart?

I did create a binary which controllably fails with segfault. This one is getting restarted. But the production one, with segfault happening randomly after couple of days - didnt restart.

**UPDATE**: adding docker engine log as per @BMitch suggestion.
Checked with `journalctl -u docker`. The only mentions of the container in question:

```
Jul 01 08:29:01 compute dockerd[2510]: time="2023-07-01T08:29:01.271312152Z" level=info msg="ignoring event" container=7a106fcac7e9ac7cac60ee8f4d29c2e494978ebb73efd27f7e8e46cffb515662 module=libcontaine>
Jul 01 08:29:01 compute dockerd[2510]: time="2023-07-01T08:29:01.302830216Z" level=warning msg="ShouldRestart failed, container will not be restarted" container=7a106fcac7e9ac7cac60ee8f4d29c2e494978ebb7>
Jul 01 09:50:08 compute dockerd[2510]: time="2023-07-01T09:50:08.438190477Z" level=info msg="Container failed to exit within 10s of signal 15 - using the force" container=7a106fcac7e9ac7cac60ee8f4d29c2e>
Jul 01 09:50:08 compute dockerd[2510]: time="2023-07-01T09:50:08.859449217Z" level=info msg="ignoring event" container=7a106fcac7e9ac7cac60ee8f4d29c2e494978ebb73efd27f7e8e46cffb515662 module=libcontaine>
Jul 01 09:50:08 compute dockerd[2510]: time="2023-07-01T09:50:08.891188155Z" level=warning msg="ShouldRestart failed, container will not be restarted" container=7a106fcac7e9ac7cac60ee8f4d29c2e494978ebb7>
```

I think the first one is when there was a segfault, the second one - is when I started container to get core dump and then stopped it. Why `ShouldRestart` fails, how can I confirm that this is the problem?

Comment: Check the logs of the docker engine.